# How to access a database for a java app that is used on other computers?

Tags: mysql, hosting, remote-access, remote-server

I am currently working on a university project which involves creating a simple java app to be run on other peoples computers as an executable jar file. As part of this, a database is required to hold login information (I am using mysql, but could use a different one). I currently have my app working locally, as my database is set up locally, but I am wondering how to best approach accessing a database remotely so that other people can use the app on their own computers, and all login information will be stored in the same database. I am very new to this, so some walk-through advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question is extremely vague. Please can you edit it to say specifically where you are getting stuck and share some code about what you have tried already or a connection string (without passwords) so others can help.

Comment: There are some options. The first option is to access remotely to some server that provides free MySQL (https://remotemysql.com); however, you need to add some logic to detect if the internet is available for your app and you can reach the remote MySQL server. The other option is to make an installer. If your project doesn't required the use of MySQL but any other database then perhaps check SQLite and set it up so you can use in memory instead of locally. In that way, you can send it all together in the jar.

Comment: @acarlstein I did already try remotemysql.com, but could not understand how to connect it to the app

Comment: @hiro228 would you mind to add details of what you tried to do into your question? How did you tried to connect? What information was provided to you? The more information you provide the easier is to help you out.